# Materialize Modal and Dropdown Problems with Meteor Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, materialize

I recently ran into some problems when trying to use the Materialize modal and dropdown features with Blaze, specifically when there are multiple instances of each.

I have this template called `cadcall`:

```
<template name="cadcall">
    <tr>
        <td class="truncate">{{id}}</td>
        <td>FRI</td>
        <td>{{time}}</td>
        <td>{{type}}</td>
        <td>{{location}}</td>
        <td>{{notes}}</td>
        <td>
          <a href=""><i class="material-icons call-dropdown-button" data-activates="cadcallactions">more_vert</i></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <div id="call-details-modal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <h4>Call Details</h4>
            <div class="row">
                <form class="new-call col s12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input id="call-id" type="text" class="validate" disabled>
                            <label for="call-id">ID</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-field col s6">
                            <input id="call-time" type="text" class="validate" disabled>
                            <label for="call-time">Time</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <input id="call-location" type="text" autocomplete="off">
                            <label for="call-location">Location</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <textarea id="call-notes" class="materialize-textarea" length="100000" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
                            <label for="call-notes">Notes</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-grey btn-flat center">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul id='cadcallactions' class='dropdown-content'>
      <li><a class="callupdate" href=""><i class="material-icons">update</i>Update</a></li>
      <li><a class="callresolve" href=""><i class="material-icons">check</i>Resolve</a></li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

Here is the `cadcall` events:

```
Template.cadcall.events({
   'click .callresolve'(e) {
      Calls.remove(this._id);
   },
});
```

Here is the `cadcall` onRendered:

```
Template.cadcall.onRendered(function() {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.call-details').leanModal();
  });
  $('.call-dropdown-button').dropdown({
      inDuration: 300,
      outDuration: 225,
      constrainWidth: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
      hover: false, // Activate on hover
      gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
      belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
      alignment: 'right', // Displays dropdown with edge aligned to the left of button
      stopPropagation: false // Stops event propagation
    });
});
```

Essentially, for each call there is in the Mongo database, I iterate each call entry.  However, if there are multiple calls, the modal doesn't function correctly.  If I try to close the modal (by clicking the class `callupdate` after opening it, the gray area behind it stays.

In addition to the modal not working correctly, the dropdown menu also acts funky, specifically when I try to delete a field (by clicking the class `callresolve`).  Whenever I try to delete a call entry it works, but thereafter the dropdown menus on the other call entries stop working altogether.  Furthermore, for some reason when I add an entry then delete it, an error pops up in the Chrome console:

```
blaze.js:650 Uncaught Error: Must be attached
    at Blaze._DOMRange.DOMRange.containsElement (blaze.js:650)
    at Blaze._DOMRange.<anonymous> (blaze.js:2612)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (blaze.js:863)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery.js:4723)
    at HTMLTableSectionElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4391)
```

Presumably, since these problems only occur when I have multiple call entries, I think the HTML may be conflicting with each iteration of the call entry.  Is there a way to remedy this issue?

Comment: Check how many times the onRendered() function is called. It might not like that $('.call-details').leanModal(); is called too many times

Comment: @JohnSmith Yeah, I tried it, and it was called 7 times since there are 7 call entries.  How would I fix it so that each modal is attached to the template but don't conflict with each other?